# error:failed retrieve data for this request

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to attach my database to SQL server 2008(I used it before without problem),but now when I want to attach db , sqlsrv sent me this error.

error:`failed retrieve data for this request.`

[image]

Why do I have this problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the SQL Server Service account has modify permissions over the physical mdf and ldf file on the hard drive that you are trying to attach to a SQL Server instance, and modify permissions also over the folder that contains the file